# Get checked Radio Button Value from JSP to Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

In HTML/JSP,

```
<input type="radio" value="10" name="a">10 Records
<input type="radio" value="20" name="a">20 Records
<input type="radio" value="50" name="a">50 Records
```

In Servlet,

```
String val= request.getParameter("a");
System.out.println("Record is : "+val);
```

Variable `val` returns `null` .

Comment: Are you sure you have one selected when you submit?

Comment: how do you post it ?

Comment: yes it is one selected when i submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you have code similar to this then it'll give you value of `a`

```
<form action="/Servlet" method="post">
     <input type="radio" value="10" name="a">10 Records
     <input type="radio" value="20" name="a">20 Records
     <input type="radio" value="50" name="a">50 Records 
    // submit button here
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

check whether your form specifies the method post. please refer below

```
<form action="/Servlet" method="post">
     <input type="radio" value="10" name="a">10 Records
     <input type="radio" value="20" name="a">20 Records
     <input type="radio" value="50" name="a">50 Records 
     <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>
```

then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem. I try this then it works fine.

```
<input type="radio" value="10" name="a">10 Records **</input>**
<input type="radio" value="20" name="a">20 Records **</input>**
<input type="radio" value="50" name="a">50 Records **</input>**
```